# What's the proper way to add a user space HID/USB driver to an existing Mac app?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos, hid

I'm wondering how I can go about adding user-space HID driver code to an existing Mac application? Since you can technically get away with writing an entire user space driver in one file would I just add that individual file (or preferably several classes) to the existing projects file tree?

Eventually this app will need to have the ability to access serial devices as well which would require a kext. Would I be able to add that directly in as well? That is of less importance at the moment though.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: you have to add the kernel module while installation and then (launch/provide service to) other apps for accessing the HID/USB device.

Comment: @bikram990 I'm not quite sure I follow, would this be the case even if the driver is in userspace?

Comment: no the drivers will be loaded as a kernel module and will be in root context.

Comment: So in that case would adding the IOKit to the linked libraries in the build phase of the existing application and then adding the driver code the HID device should take care of it?

Comment: Didn't understand that. So are you trying to add the driver code in Application? that wouldn't work straight forward.

Comment: @bikram990 yea basically we have an existing application being built up by one part of the team, I'm working on the User-space driver code outside of the application code base.I will need to merge it in with the application code base though. We were under the impression I could add IOKit to app and then bring in my files as necessary.

Comment: if your application is going to use that USB device then its fine. but if you are planing to make it available to other applications also then it will be tough in application layer.